# Shipment Tracking in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

iOS 4 automatically detects tracking numbers found in emails, notes, and messages and turns them into clickable links.

[image: Shipping Image]

And it redirects to this URL,

http://trackingshipment.apple.com/?Company=UPS&Locale=&TrackingNumber=1Z1234567890123456

How can we use this API or library into our iOS apps so it will automatically detect or force detect shipping numbers?

Comment: do you want to scan the user's e-mail for this info though?

Comment: no, for example I have a UITextField, and I will like it to detect either its from UPS, USPS, Fedex etc and have the tracking link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the publicly-released data detector types don't include common carrier tracking numbers. I wrote a small project showing how to detect UPS, USPS, and FedEx package numbers and got pretty good results:

[image: Tracking Code Demo]

You'll have to do the work of assembling the tracking URLs yourself, but this sample code may help you get started. [Download here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13103695/Shipments.zip).

Comment: thanks! this is great! that's what I was looking for! and lol at the Copying copyright file.

Comment: I'm glad you take it in the spirit it was offered :) I believe sharing liberally affords greater dividends than trying to restrict peoples' use of my creative output.

Comment: Is there any way you could upload this again?

Answer (score 2):

The class being used to do this is called [NSDataDetector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

It is a subclass of `NSRegularExpression` where you can specify some built in patterns to look for.

The list of built in type values in the `NSTextCheckingType` enum can be seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextCheckingResult_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSTextCheckingType).

I don't see one specifically for tracking information, but the closest thing appears to be `NSTextCheckingTypeTransitInformation`. That is most likely the one you're going to be using.

Good luck!